# How to run tasks of my Gradle project in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle

I have create a Gradle Java app via the [Gradle tutorial](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications.html) the top-level directory structure looks like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── lib
│   └── src
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle
```

I adjusted `build.gradle` to point to my local maven mirror (the machine has no internet connection) and now I can in the terminal run Gradle tasks with

```
$ gradle run
```

and

```
$ gradle build
```

So far so good.

I then installed the [Gradle extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-gradle) and opened the project in VS Code, but I cannot see these two tasks anywhere. VS Code's Gradle view shows only this:

[image]

Also when I try from the menu *Terminal* -> *Run Task..* -> *gradle*, then VS Code says "No Gradle tasks found".

**Where/how does the Gradle extension show the Gradle tasks of my the project?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code doesn't see the local Gradle install by defaukt. It tries to download Gradle  again and this fails here (because the machine has no internet).

In VS Code set `java.import.gradle.home` and `java.import.gradle.wrapper.enabled` appropriately:

[image: Gradle settinsg in VS Code]